# Hard to find a good rewriting rule

Tags: url-rewriting

I need to rewrite an adress for my WP site. I encounter difficulties, and I may need your kindfull help.

In fact, in need to rewrite

`www.sitename.com/?post_type=portfolio&portfolio-category=a-category&portfolio-tag=a-tag`

into

`www.sitename.com/my-search&your-category=a-category&your-tag=a-tag`

How can I do this thanks to functions.php or .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite rules are intended to convert *ugly* urls (containing with `&` and `?`) into [pretty urls](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#mod_rewrite%3a_.22Pretty_Permalinks.22) not the countrary.

So I think you need a redirect more than a rewrite rule:

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'my_custom_redirect', 1);

function my_custom_redirect() {

  if ( filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'post_type', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) === 'portfolio' ) {
     $cat = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'portfolio-category', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
     $tag = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'portfolio-tag', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
     if ( empty($cat) || empty($tag) ) return;
     $baseurl = home_url('/my-search');
     $url = add_query_arg( array('your-category' => $cat, 'your-tag' => $tag), $baseurl );
     wp_safe_redirect($url);
     exit();
  }

}
```